# Get Selected Item Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is an example to what I mean:

```
public class country
{
    public int pk_country { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public lang lang { get; set; }
}

public enum lang
{
    en = 44,
    fr = 33
}

public class person
{

    string name { get; set; }

    public country country { get; set; }

    int pk_country { get; set; }

    decimal basicSalary { get; set; }

    decimal actualSalary { get { if (country.lang == lang.en) return (decimal)15.99 * basicSalary; else return basicSalary + (decimal)14.99; } }
}
```

In the MVC app, the user keys in the name, Country (DropDown Select List so we only passing the pk_country) and basic salary.
When initiating person class, however, the country object is null therefore this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Is there a way so that the country object properties know their values based on the selected value pk_country passed from the view.

In my project, I'm using a ViewModel and I don't wish to make database requests i.e getting the dataset for the selected pk_country to determine the lang

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick it from database because i'm sure you don't have limited number of countries but you can get rid of this exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

by just initializing the country object associated with Person instance in its constructor

```
public class person{

 public person(){ country=new country(); }string name { get; set; }

public country country { get; set; }

int pk_country { get; set; }

decimal basicSalary { get; set; }

decimal actualSalary { get { if (country.lang == lang.en) return (decimal)15.99 * basicSalary; else return basicSalary + (decimal)14.99; } }}
```

Comment: but the new object in the consutructor does not know about the value selected i.e the pk_country. I mean I can add the use this.pk_country however I still need  country.lang  to determine the ActualSalary. The ActualSalary is determined by  country.lang.

Comment: Yes the "lang" object is null too for this you can instantiate lang in country constructor or inject its dependency into it

Comment: Yes I agree the object needs to be initiated however this means I need to get the data from db in the viewModel. I have put in an example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zq5En4. Please let me know thanks brother

Comment: @Khalil in this property you are accessing "Country.CountryLanguage" but the Country associated with Person is NULL this time so you have to instantiate Country property in Person Class                                                                                                             public decimal ActualSalary {   get { if (Country.CountryLanguage == Language.En){ return (decimal) 15.00 * Salary;
                    } else {
                        return (decimal)10.00 * Salary;
                    }
            }
        }

Comment: public Person(){ Country=new Country()} simple

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `person` entity to be stored, you have to load the `country` using the selected ID and assign it. There is no way around this.

```
public person CreatePerson(string name, decimal basicSalary, int countryId) {
    var person = new person {
        name = name,
        basicSalary = basicSalary
    };

    var country = _dbContext.Country.Find(countryId);
    person.country = country;

    _dbContext.Person.Add(person);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return person;
}
```

When you load an existing `person` from the DB, `country` can be loaded automatically (lazy loading) if configured correctly. See [Lazy Loading in Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx).

Additional note: your class and property names do not respect the C# naming conventions. Class and property names should start with an uppercase character, e.g. `Person` instead of `person`, `BasicSalary` instead of `basicSalary`. Only variable names should start with a lowercase character.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. When creating Person, Country Object is null, therefore the null exception is thrown when setting ActualSalary ( country.lang is null too as the ActualSalary is set based in the value of country.lang). I'm not tempting to do a db call from the ViewModel. I am keeping all the db calls in the controller

Comment: I probably do not understand the flow of data in your project. I thought along the lines: User fills in create person form and submits it -> Controller creates the person entity (like shown above) -> newly created person is displayed to the user, including actual salary. Basically you do a POST -> redirect -> GET.

Comment: You are right with the flow. However I am struggling to get it to work. I have put an example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zq5En4. You will see the error too. I need somehow to create the Country Object before creating the person object. Please let me know thanks